# DirectX DXUT alternate API

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, dxut

Does  anybody  know  if there are some  alternate API  for  Direct X,  i mean  just  GUI  library !  without  Direct X  re-implementation  like we had  in DXUT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows Store and universal Windows apps on Windows 10, you can use XAML+DirectX interop to get right GUI on top of a Direct3D surface. See [DirectX - Using XAML with DirectX and C++ in Windows Store Apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991975.aspx).

In general Win32 GUI APIs do not render on Direct3D surfaces. That is why the "widgets" in [DXUT](https://github.com/Microsoft/DXUT) exist in the first place. There is also a similar solution implemented in [ImGui](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui).

Many games make use of middleware solutions like [ScaleForm](http://gameware.autodesk.com/scaleform).

Comment: Thanks  Chucky,   interesting  advice  i will  choose  one of  them  i  hope.

Answer (score 0):

Direct3D can be mounted in arbitrary Windows window object. You can use any MFC, WTL, VCL or wxWidgets window through window handle (`HWND`) (it means button, panel, and more), and build with it arbitrary user interfaces.

The only restriction Direct3D must be configured in a windowed mode.